# Manage caption Close Button's click in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Window where I want to shut down the app if the user press the red X(Close) button. For this, I handle the *Closing* event and make `Environment.Exit(0);`

If the user ends working with the Window and clicks Accept I want to close it, but if I make `this.Close();`, this will trigger the *Closing* event and shut down the whole App.

I tried to check the *sender* param of the event with the debugger but it´s the Window object in both cases. Is there a way to check the source element of the Event trigger?

I could use a flag, setting it to true when the user clicks Accept and don't make the `Environment.Exit(0);` when it´s true, but I don´t think this is a clean solution.

Comment: "...but I don´t think this is a clean solution." - Why?

Comment: And you should use `Application.Current.Shutdown()` instead.

Comment: @CodingGorilla It would mix the functions responsability. I mean, the responsability of the closing handler would be from "Shut down if the source is the red button" to "Shut down if some other strange function didnt set a flag"

Comment: @Evans I think you're over thinking the problem; personally I think using a flag in that way is perfectly acceptable.  Aside from doing a flag as you descibed, I don't see any way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 3):

OnClosing trigger is call when there is a attempt to close the window. You can cancel it with your condition (flag, or confirmation box)

```
// exemple with flag
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.allowedToClose == false)
    {
        // this window will not close
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else if (this.appMustClose == true)
    {
        // close the app
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Set e.Cancel to true to cancel the closing. Let it to false and the windows will close. You don't need to use Environment.Exit, except if the window is not the main window.

You can use Application.Current.Shutdown() instead of Environment.Exit(0). I think it's proper.

Comment: The OP was not asking how to cancel closing the window.

Comment: the answer resolve all cases : closing the window or not, closing the application or not. OP asked if it was clean to use Closing trigger, that's help him to do what he want.